# Caching Specific Objects in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, caching

I have a couple of objects stored in my database which are frequently loaded by my application. I was thinking of caching these objects to get a better performance.

The problem with Hibernate Cache is that you can't tell it to cache specific objects, so it caches every instance of the specified entities.

I tried saving the objects in my own cache data structure, but the problem is that the cached object might have relationships with other objects and so objects will require the cache entries to be discarded/reloaded.

Can anybody suggest any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your use case by making use of Query Caching in Hibernate.

Please see sample code below:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee e where e.id=1");
query.setCacheable(true);
List list = query.list()
query = session.createQuery("from Employee e where e.id=1");
query.setCacheable(true);
List list = query.list();
```

Please take a look at official documnetation below:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-querycache-enable